# Get relative shape location in visio

Tags: visio

I am generating a shape report to list x,y locations of all my shapes.
The report includes "Display Text", "X location" and "Y location".

The "X location" and "Y location" are equivalent to the PinX and PinY properties in the shape sheet. However these does not reflect the page grid, and do not refer to an origin (0,0), so the coordinates are all offset with some value.

I would like all coordinates to refer to the left lower corner of a specific rectangle, that surrounds my reported shapes.
[image: Shows the PinX property from the shapesheet reported in the table not matching the x location of the shape.]

Answer (score 4):

Please check that all shapes have rotate point in center of shape (by default), not in bottom-left corner of shape!
[image]
**PinX**/**PinY** values you can see in **Size & Position Window**
In bottom of this window you can find field named **Pin** **Pos**.
[image]
This field corresponds to a combination of a pair of values in cells **LocPinX** & **LocPinY**. This is what caused the offset !
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to change the page (0,0) also so that the reported <X Location> and <Y Location> becomes relative to that?

Ideally I would like to put in an arbitrary shape, and then report all figures X, Y position relative to that new shapes position.